# How to concurrently take items from the BlockingCollection?

Tags: c#, multithreading, multitasking, blockingcollection

I have a `BlockingCollection` of integers.
Below is the code I am trying to develop to remove the items concurrently from the `BlockingCollection`.

```
static void Produce()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            bc3.Add(i);
        }
        Run();
    }

    static void Run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Process, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        }
    }

    static void Process()
    {
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        while (bc3.Count!= 0)
        {
            bc3.Take();
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}",
        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time {0}", stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds);

    }
```

Is this the correct way remove items in a faster way by creating 5 tasks?

Comment: 5 tasks? It takes 16 milliseconds on my machine. Task 1 even cleans the collection before Windows was able to start any other thread.

Comment: Your code seems to assume that all items have already been added to the collection before you start removing them. If that's the case, then a ConcurrentQueue will perform much better than the BlockingCollection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Stopwatch issue

Your measurement results are wrong because you use

```
stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds
```

instead of

```
stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

You only display the seconds, but ignore the minutes, hours, etc.

#### Concurrency issue

No, this is not the correct way of removing items from a BlockingCollection. The statement that does not work is

```
bc3.Count != 0
```

All 5 tasks may check this condition at the same time, finding out that there is 1 item left. They all 5 go to

```
bc3.Take();
```

One task is able to remove the item, the other 4 tasks are waiting.

One way to solve this is to add

```
bc3.CompleteAdding();
```

in `Produce()`.

#### Garbage collection issue

Once the first task finishes, the `Run()` method completes and all tasks in the method go out of scope and are garbage collected. This may make you see only 1 instead of 5 completion messages.

To fix this, use

```
    static void Run()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(Process, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
        }
        try
        {
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }
        catch (AggregateException)
        { }        
    }
```

#### Cost of synchronization

Here's one of my outputs with 5 tasks (and 100000000 items):

```
Thread 11
Thread 13
Thread 12
Thread 14
Thread 15
Elapsed Time 12878
Elapsed Time 13122
Elapsed Time 13128
Elapsed Time 13128
Elapsed Time 13128
Run: 13140
```

Compare this to a single task:

```
Thread 12
Elapsed Time 10147
Run: 10149
```

This is because only one Take() method can remove an item and it takes additional time for synchronization.

Comment: Perfectly correct, but I would assume that once this is scaffolded into place, the *real work* done by each consumer would bury the synchronization overhead, but +1 for covering all the bases.

Comment: `Once the first task finishes, the Run() method completes and all tasks in the method go out of scope and are garbage collected` This isn't an issue. While queued, the task are referenced by the TaskScheduler. Then when running it's not an issue either because threads are rooted. Even if the task instance is collected, it won't prevent the work to be done (assuming the program doesn't exit before the end)

Comment: @KevinGosse: I initially thought that as well, but I never saw the Console.Writeline()s of the remaining tasks on my screen, even if I put them into a finally-block.